# ggraph/igraph show uncorrece label and hierarchical structure

Tags: r, tidyverse, igraph, ggraph

`ggraph/igraph`, the result in below plot isn't correct :

1)The amount of DE is 4.5, but the sub circles are 8.8 and 9 (the correct amount should be "DE cat_a   3.0, DE cat_b   1.5")

2. there is no sub circle for UK/US

How to fix it ? Thanks!

```
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)

base <- data.frame(from =c('US','US','UK','UK','DE','DE'),
                   to = c('cat_a','cat_b','cat_a','cat_b','cat_a','cat_b'),
                   sales=c(1,3,5,4,3,1.5))

vetic <- base %>% gather(key='type', value ='dim',c(1:2)) %>% 
  group_by(dim) %>% summarise(sales = sum(sales)) 

mdf <- graph_from_data_frame(base,directed = TRUE,vertices = vetic)


ggraph(mdf, layout = 'circlepack', weight=sales) + 
  geom_node_circle(aes(fill = depth)) +
    geom_node_text(size=10,aes(label= paste0(name,'\n',sales)))+
  theme_void()+scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdPu")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with how you are creating your graph. It seems you want to show the amount of `cat_a` and `cat_b` within each country, but you are creating the graph as though `cat_a` and `cat_b` are each a single node. If you want a `cat_a` and a `cat_b` node inside each country, then you need to specify them as distinct nodes.

For example, we can do:

```r
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)

base <- data.frame(from =c('US','US','UK','UK','DE','DE'),
                   to = c('cat_a','cat_b','cat_a','cat_b','cat_a','cat_b'),
                   sales=c(1,3,5,4,3,1.5))

base_fixed <- base %>% mutate(to = paste(from, to))
```

Which gives the following data frame:

```r
base_fixed
#>   from       to sales
#> 1   US US cat_a   1.0
#> 2   US US cat_b   3.0
#> 3   UK UK cat_a   5.0
#> 4   UK UK cat_b   4.0
#> 5   DE DE cat_a   3.0
#> 6   DE DE cat_b   1.5
```

Similarly, the vertices should have a label and value for each of the resulting 9 nodes (3 country nodes, plus two "cat" nodes within each):

```r
vertices <- base_fixed %>%
  group_by(from) %>%
  summarize(sales = sum(sales)) %>%
  rbind(base_fixed %>% select(-1) %>% rename(from = to))

vertices
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#>   from     sales
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 DE         4.5
#> 2 UK         9  
#> 3 US         4  
#> 4 US cat_a   1  
#> 5 US cat_b   3  
#> 6 UK cat_a   5  
#> 7 UK cat_b   4  
#> 8 DE cat_a   3  
#> 9 DE cat_b   1.5
```

The graph could then be drawn as follows:

```r
graph_from_data_frame(base_fixed, vertices = vertices) %>%
  ggraph(layout = 'circlepack', weight = sales) + 
  geom_node_circle(aes(fill = depth)) +
  geom_node_text(size = 5, 
                 aes(label = ifelse(depth == 0, '',
                      paste0(substr(name, 4, 20), '\n', sales)))) +
  geom_node_label(size = 6, aes(label = ifelse(depth == 1, NA,
                   substr(name, 1, 2)))) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdPu", guide = 'none') +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>